# Alpha estimation from factor models

Tags: factor-models, fama-french

This question makes reference to section 8.4 - Application to performance measure - of the 2007 publication "Performance Measurement for Traditional Investment" by Véronique Le Sourd. You can find the paper [here](https://risk.edhec.edu/sites/risk/files/EDHEC_Publi_performance_measurement_for_traditional_investment.pdf).

In her article, the author states that the implementation of factor models is carried out in two stages (if I understand correctly, she refers to the Fama Macbeth methodology). First, betas are estimated by means of a series of time series regressions of asset returns (one for each asset $i$) on factor returns:

$(1)$ $R_{it} = \beta_{i0} + \sum_{k=1}^K\beta_{ik}F_{kt}+\epsilon_{it}$

Then, lambdas are estimated running a cross-sectional regression at each date $t$:

$(2)$ $R_{it} - R_f = \hat\alpha + \sum_{k=1}^K\hat\beta_{ik}\hat\lambda_{kt}+\zeta_{it}$

After calculating the average risk premiums as:

$(3)$ $\lambda_k = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_{kt}$

She states that fund performance is given by:

$(4)$ $\alpha_i = \bar{R_i} - \bar{R_f} - \sum_{k=1}^K\hat{\beta_{ik}}\lambda_k$

What is not clear to me is why one would estimate alpha as in equation $(4)$ instead of simply considering as alpha the estimate of the coefficient called $\beta_{i0}$ in equation $(1)$.

For instance, if I were to employ the Fama-French three-factor model to estimate alpha, should I follow the procedure above or simply estimate alpha as the intercept of the following regression?

$R_{it} - R_{ft} = \alpha_i + \beta_i(R_{mt}-R_{ft}) + s_iSMB_t + h_iHML_t + \epsilon_{it}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of the method is that you can use it regardless of whether the factor is traded or non-traded. If the factor is traded, you are correct, you can use time-series tests and test whether the intercept is zero ($\beta_{i0}$) in your case.

We are testing whether $\beta_{i0}=$ in:

$R_{it} = \beta_{i0} + \sum_{k=1}^K\beta_{ik}F_{kt}+\epsilon_{it}$

In other words, we are testing whether the pricing errors are simply a
product of "normal" sample variation or in fact a result of a misspecified
model.

The steps to perform time-series regressions (instead of Fama-McBethe) are:

1. Run $N$ separate regressions for each asset $i$
2. Get the sample vector of residuals $\epsilon_{it}$
3. Calculate the variance covariance matrix of residuals $\hat{\Sigma}$
4. Gibbons, Ross, and Shanken (1987) show us that when we have to estimate the covariance matrix, the joint test become:

$\frac{T-N-1}{N}\frac{1}{\theta_p^2} \hat{\beta_{0}}' \hat{\Sigma}^{-1} \hat{\beta_{0}} \sim F(N,T-N-1)$ where:

$\theta_p^2 = \frac{\bar{F}^2}{Var_T(F_t)}$

Check GRS original paper for an economic intuition of this test.